# Setting up LIRC in Debian 8

Tags: debian, remote-control

I have an infrared remote control which sends RC-5 signals and a computer with an IR receiver. The computer runs Debian 8 and I'm trying to set up LIRC so that I can control the music player daemon (MPD) with the remote.

I have installed the `lirc` package and added a [configuration file for RC-5 signals](http://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/code/ci/master/tree/remotes/generic/RC-5.lircd.conf) in `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/`.

The daemon seems to be active:

```
$ systemctl status lirc.service 
● lirc.service - LSB: Starts LIRC daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/lirc)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2016-01-31 20:18:17 CET; 32s ago
  Process: 408 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/lirc start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

However, when I try to test the remote control with `irw` it fails:

```
$ irw
connect: No such file or directory
```

According to `man irw` this seems to be cause by the absence of the socket file `/var/run/lirc/lircd`. The directory `/var/run/lirc` is empty.

Any clues would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: The daemon isn't running (`active (exited)`), so there's no socket. You need to figure out why it's exited, presumably by looking at its logs.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for the hint. It turned out that I needed to set driver and device in /enc/lirc/hardware.conf. I will soon post a complete (minimal) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated 2021-01-10 for LIRC 0.10.1*

Here are the steps I need perform to make it work.

1. Install LIRC:

   ```
    # apt install lirc
   ```
2. In `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf`, set *driver* and *device* to the following values:

   ```
    driver = default
    device = /dev/lirc0
   ```
3. Download a configuration file for the remote control and copy it to `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/`. Make sure the file ends with `.conf`. In my case the protocol is RC-5 and I found a working configuration file at http://lirc.sourceforge.net/remotes/rc-5/RC-5.
4. Restart the LIRC daemon:

   ```
    # systemctl restart lircd
   ```
5. To find out the name for each button, run `irw`, point the remote control to the IR receiver and press buttons.
6. Specify what should happen when a button is pressed in the file `/etc/lirc/irexec.lircrc`. Here is the file I created for MPD:

   ```
    begin
        button = sys_14_command_21
        prog   = irexec
        config = mpc prev
    end

    begin
        button = sys_14_command_20
        prog   = irexec
        config = mpc next
    end

    begin
        button = sys_14_command_35
        prog   = irexec
        config = mpc play
    end

    begin
        button = sys_14_command_30
        prog   = irexec
        config = mpc pause
    end

    begin
        button = sys_14_command_36
        prog   = irexec
        config = mpc stop
    end
   ```
7. Start irexec:

   ```
    # systemctl start irexec
   ```
8. Run irexec at startup:

   ```
    # systemctl enable irexec
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this and the only way for me to make it work was to run:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lircd --driver=default --device=/dev/lirc0
```

Under:

```
 Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

This seems to create the directory needed for the pid and socket connection!? I could be wrong but after a lot of testing that was the only substantial change I've made.

Once I have a fresh installation I'll confirm this and post all the commands I ran

Comment: There have been quite a few changes in LIRC since my first reply. I have now updated the instructions for LIRC 0.10.1 (which comes with Debian 10).